# (OS X) How to be notified when user switches mac desktop space

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I'm creating a Mac menu bar app that I'd like to be notified when the user switches the visible desktop space (including external monitors). This is a menu bar only app (i.e no actual window).

I've seen a few similar questions, but none of the answers seemed to work for me. Most answers I've seen involve observing `NSWorkspaceActiveSpaceDidChangeNotification` on the `NSWorkspace`'s notification center.

I've tried observing this in my AppDelegate in `applicationDidFinishLaunching` I have the following code:

`NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().notificationCenter.addObserver(self,
  selector: Selector(spaceChanged()),
  name: NSWorkspaceActiveSpaceDidChangeNotification,
  object: nil)`

In my `spaceChanged()` function I'm just printing something to console for debugging purposes. This function only ever gets called on app launch. Whenever I change the desktop space though I never get notified.

Is there something I'm missing? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than `Selector(spaceChanged())` you should use `#selector(spaceChanged)`. With `Selector(spaceChanged())`, you're actually calling this function immediately, and using the result (which is probably just an empty tuple `()`) to create a null selector. The latter syntax actually creates the proper selector referencing your `spaceChanged` function.

Comment: wow, thanks a lot! I ended up looking into the two a bit more and for anyone interested, this is a helpful post: http://en.swifter.tips/selector/. Thanks again @jtbandes

Comment: An update with Swift 5:
``
        NSWorkspace.shared.notificationCenter.addObserver(
            self,
            selector: #selector(spaceChanged),
            name: NSWorkspace.activeSpaceDidChangeNotification,
            object: nil
        )
``

Answer (score 4):

An update for Swift:

```
    NSWorkspace.shared.notificationCenter.addObserver(
        self,
        selector: #selector(spaceChanged),
        name: NSWorkspace.activeSpaceDidChangeNotification,
        object: nil
    )
```